# What is this 6-pin IC on board?

Tags: identification

What is this 6-pin IC on board?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that the IC has the label X17. and we know that its a 6 pin SMD IC. You can google "X17 6 pin SOIC" and you will get the first result with the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I've just tried that, and don't get actually get the Rohm IMX17, which I think is the part in question.  Was this the exact search phrase you used on google, and what was the part it threw up?

Answer (score 5):

The code and package fits with a Rohm IMX17 dual NPN transistor. Digikey page [here](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/rohm-semiconductor/IMX17T108/2336897).

Comment: Amazing! Would you mind sharing your methods for conducting these kinds of investigations?

Comment: There are a number of SMD code databases (a web search with thrown up several), which allow lookup on code, then you can assess the matches based on package and PCB/function.

Comment: You can also look in the data sheets at placement of the printing, and also batch codes to help provide confirmation.